# Sample vs. sample values

Tags: sampling, terminology

Is there any difference between the terms *sample* and *sample value* in DSP? In statistics, those are [very different concepts](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/173337/24265): a sample is a subset of a population: it is a set of random variables. A sample value is the [realization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_(probability)) (aka. observed value) of this set.

[image]

In DSP, I feel that *sample* is often used with the same meaning as *sample value*:

[image]

Comment: in audio and music DSP, sometimes end users of the audio processing or music synthesis or sample-playback software use the term *"sample"* to mean the entire sound file (like a .wav or .aiff) of the note or sound event (all of $x[n]$ for $0 \le n < N $) and not just a single $x[n]$, which might be called a *"sample value"*.  as a DSP coder, i would use the semantic that a single $x[n]$ is a *"sample"*.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Thanks, good point that's right, "vocal sample", "sample packs", "sampling a song", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the confusion comes from *sampling theory*. Thus, when you *sample* a signal, you get ... *samples*. If you want to be clear you can call the other one a *statistical sample*.